# Kibana 7.14 | Date Format - Is it possible to store Dates in Epoch format but display it in ISO Date format in Kibana Search queries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to Store the Date in Epoch format but display it in ISO Date format within the Kibana search queries?

Note - The below diagram depicts how the date should be displayed in different places. Most questions on stack overflow are just about changing formats when writing into ES but I am wondering if there is a way to change the format when the date is displaying in Kibana.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it is by using [`script_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#script-fields) like this:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "date_iso": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc.date.value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results =>

```
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "date" : "1635972005107"
    },
    "fields" : {
      "date_iso" : [
        "2021-11-03T20:40:05.107Z"
      ]
    }
  }
```

As you can see, even though the `date` field is stored in epoch format, the `date_iso` script field is returned in ISO8601 format.

You can also use the [Fields API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#search-fields-param) to return the `date` with the given format:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "field": "date",
      "format": "date_time" 
    }
  ]
}
```

Results =>

```
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "date" : "1635972005107"
    },
    "fields" : {
      "date" : [
        "2021-11-03T20:40:05.107Z"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to override the date field directly? As opposed to showing this under a separate field.

Comment: you can tell Kibana to use UTC when it displays timestamps, but that's an instance wide setting

Comment: @Dinesh which ES version are you running?

Comment: @Val - I am using ES v7.11.1

Comment: @MarkWalkom - Actually instance-wide would be great in my case. Are you able to point me to any documentation on how to configure Kibana to use UTC?

Comment: @Dinesh it's in Stack Management > Advanced Settings > Date format

Comment: @Val - hmm.. interesting.. Under Advanced Setttings > the Date format is already set as `MMM D, YYYY @ HH:mm:ss.SSS`. But in my queries, they are being displayed in epoch format. I even tried it with `?pretty` parameter. But no luck.